# Play console error - some languages have error

Tags: android, google-play-console, playback

I'm getting an error in the store listing while uploading an app to the Google Play Console - 'Some languages ​​have an error'
How to solve this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was on line with their chat person (bot?), zero help. Could not answer the question. Extremely frustrating. It took me about 2 minutes to add my app to the Amazon App Store. 4 days of misery with Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

This a common problem.
There's nothing to worry

here's the solution:

1. Make sure that you have completed all the (*) marked listing'
2. And then, Click on "SAVE"